# Syntax Error in Join Operation with new SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, ms-access-2010

I have an access database that links to another access database.  Within the latter, there's a table hosted on a SQL server.  I used to have it on a local table, and had no issues with the query, but now that it's on SQL, I keep getting errors.  Help would be great!

```
SELECT Year([date])                                                  AS [YEAR], 
   Month([date])                                                 AS [MONTH], 
   [bear revenue].[CustomerNum], 
   Iif([customernum] LIKE "g*", 99999999, 
   Iif([customernum] LIKE "*w*", Replace([customernum], "0w", 99), Iif( 
   [customernum] LIKE "*i*", Replace([customernum], "0i", 98), Iif( 
   [customernum] LIKE "*-*", LEFT( 
   [customernum], 5), [customernum]))))                          AS 
   [Customer No], 
   [bear revenue].asc, 
   [bear revenue].account, 
   [bear revenue].department, 
   [bear revenue].[FeeType], 
   Sum([bear revenue].[Loan_Count])                              AS 
   [SumOfLOAN COUNT], 
   Sum([bear revenue].revenue)                                   AS 
   SumOfREVENUE, 
   Sum(Iif([refund rate] <> 0, [loan_count] * [refund rate], 0)) AS refund, 
   [bear revenue].system 
FROM   bear Revenue 
       LEFT JOIN [current customer refunds] 
              ON ( [bear revenue].[CustomerNum] = 
[current customer refunds].[refund customer numbers] ) 
AND ( [bear revenue].[FeeType] = 
[current customer refunds].[feetype] ) 
GROUP  BY Year([date]), 
          Month([date]), 
          [bear revenue].[CustomerNum], 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "g*", 99999999, 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "*w*", Replace([customernum], "0w", 99), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*i*", Replace([customernum], "0i", 98), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*-*", LEFT( 
          [customernum], 5), [customernum])))), 
          [bear revenue].asc, 
          [bear revenue].account, 
          [bear revenue].department, 
          [bear revenue].[FeeType], 
          [bear revenue].system 
HAVING ( ( ( Year([date]) ) = 2013 ) 
         AND ( ( Month([date]) ) = 10 ) ) 
ORDER  BY Year([date]), 
          Month([date]), 
          [bear revenue].[CustomerNum], 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "g*", 99999999, 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "*w*", Replace([customernum], "0w", 99), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*i*", Replace([customernum], "0i", 98), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*-*", LEFT( 
          [customernum], 5), [customernum])))), 
          [bear revenue].asc, 
          [bear revenue].account, 
          [bear revenue].[FeeType];
```

Comment: Like @Gordon suggested an error message would help a lot.

Comment: Okay, so we're running this query in one Access database, which we'll call the "front-end". Your data tables are in another Access database, which we'll call the "back-end". You used to have a native Access table in the back-end. You moved that table to SQL Server and created a linked table entry (with the same name as the old native Access table) in the back-end that points to the SQL Server table. Your query above is unchanged. Have I described the situation correctly?

Comment: Which table did you move to SQL Server?

Comment: Bear Revenue - which is the back-end

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you post the error you are getting.  However, there seems to be an obvious problem with your query in the `from` clause.

Where you have:

```
FROM Bear Revenue
```

You should have

```
FROM [Bear Revenue]
```

You also might want to include a database and schema name if this is the remote table.

Answer (score 0):

Use [] for keyword `asc`

```
SELECT Year([date])                                                  AS [YEAR], 
   Month([date])                                                 AS [MONTH], 
   [bear revenue].[CustomerNum], 
   Iif([customernum] LIKE "g*", 99999999, 
   Iif([customernum] LIKE "*w*", Replace([customernum], "0w", 99), Iif( 
   [customernum] LIKE "*i*", Replace([customernum], "0i", 98), Iif( 
   [customernum] LIKE "*-*", LEFT( 
   [customernum], 5), [customernum]))))                          AS 
   [Customer No], 
   [bear revenue].[asc], 
   [bear revenue].account, 
   [bear revenue].department, 
   [bear revenue].[FeeType], 
   Sum([bear revenue].[Loan_Count])                              AS 
   [SumOfLOAN COUNT], 
   Sum([bear revenue].revenue)                                   AS 
   SumOfREVENUE, 
   Sum(Iif([refund rate] <> 0, [loan_count] * [refund rate], 0)) AS refund, 
   [bear revenue].system 
FROM   bear Revenue 
       LEFT JOIN [current customer refunds] 
              ON ( [bear revenue].[CustomerNum] = 
[current customer refunds].[refund customer numbers] ) 
AND ( [bear revenue].[FeeType] = 
[current customer refunds].[feetype] ) 
GROUP  BY Year([date]), 
          Month([date]), 
          [bear revenue].[CustomerNum], 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "g*", 99999999, 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "*w*", Replace([customernum], "0w", 99), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*i*", Replace([customernum], "0i", 98), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*-*", LEFT( 
          [customernum], 5), [customernum])))), 
          [bear revenue].[asc], 
          [bear revenue].account, 
          [bear revenue].department, 
          [bear revenue].[FeeType], 
          [bear revenue].system 
HAVING ( ( ( Year([date]) ) = 2013 ) 
         AND ( ( Month([date]) ) = 10 ) ) 
ORDER  BY Year([date]), 
          Month([date]), 
          [bear revenue].[CustomerNum], 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "g*", 99999999, 
          Iif([customernum] LIKE "*w*", Replace([customernum], "0w", 99), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*i*", Replace([customernum], "0i", 98), Iif( 
          [customernum] LIKE "*-*", LEFT( 
          [customernum], 5), [customernum])))), 
          [bear revenue].[asc], 
          [bear revenue].account, 
          [bear revenue].[FeeType];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a table link in your front-end database named [Bear Revenue] that points to ***an Access table*** named [Bear Revenue] in your back-end database. After you moved the [Bear Revenue] Access table to SQL Server (and replaced it with a link in the back-end to the SQL Server table), the ***actual Access table named [Bear Revenue] no longer exists*** in the back-end database. That's why the [Bear Revenue] table link in your front-end database file stopped working.

The solution is to delete the current (Access) [Bear Revenue] table link in your front-end database and replace it with an ODBC table link (also named [Bear Revenue]) that points directly to the SQL Server table.